# NetSim - distance between the sensor nodes and the various agents?

Tags: networking, simulation

In NetSim where and what code needs to be added to print the distance between the various sensors and the agents, that are being sensed by the sensors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to the source code (NetSim_Install_Directory -> src -> simulation -> Zigbee) and check the file sensor.c, which has exactly what you are asking for. The code is reproduced below -

```
_declspec(dllexport)int fn_NetSim_Zigbee_SensorEvent(int nSensorLoop,NETSIM_ID nGlobalPANCoordinatorId,AGENT** pstruAgent,SENSORS* pstru_Sensor,METRICS** pstruMetrics,NetSim_EVENTDETAILS* pstruEventDetails,IEEE802_15_4_PRIMITIVES *pstruIEEE802_15_4_Primitives)
{

.......
.....
pstruTemppos->dXPos = NETWORK->ppstruDeviceList[nSensorLoop-1]->pstruDevicePosition->X;
        pstruTemppos->dYPos = NETWORK->ppstruDeviceList[nSensorLoop-1]->pstruDevicePosition->Y;
        dDistance = fn_Sensor_CalculateDistance(pstruTemppos,pstruPos);
....
....
}

/** This function is used to find the distance between the Agent and the Sensor. */
double fn_Sensor_CalculateDistance(POS_2D* pstruPos1, POS_2D* pstruPos2)
{
    double dDistance;
    if(pstruPos1 == NULL || pstruPos2 == NULL)
        return 0;

    dDistance = (pstruPos1->dXPos - pstruPos2->dXPos)*(pstruPos1->dXPos - pstruPos2->dXPos);
    dDistance += (pstruPos1->dYPos - pstruPos2->dYPos)*(pstruPos1->dYPos - pstruPos2->dYPos);
    dDistance = sqrt(dDistance);
    return dDistance;
}
```

This section will give you the distance between any sensor and any agent. You can then print it to a file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Also can you please let me know how to plot  energy vs time graphs for each sensor in a wireless sensor network model

Comment: It is possible to get energy vs. time in WSN by writing custom code in NetSim.

In function fn_NetSim_Zigbee_ChangeRadioState of file ChangeRadioState.c
 
You could write a line like
 
fprintf(fp,"%lf\t%lf\n",pstruEventDetails->dEventTime,pstruDevicePower[nDeviceId-1]->dRemainingPower);

The rebuild and link the updated DLL to NetSim. This will print in a file the time followed by remaining power for the sensor defined by nDeviceID. Then using those value you can plot a graph in a suitable spreadsheet program.